# c# regex transforms similar to python

Tags: c#, python, regex, transform, substitution

How to i transform a url in # using regular expression in c# which is similar to this python code

```
import re
url = http://active.com
url1 = re.sub(r'(^htt[^\/]*\/\/)(.*)',r'\1www\.$2',url)
```

input:

```
http://active.com
```

expected output:

```
http://www.active.com
```

also how could i pass www. from a variable in c#

eg

```
string domain_part = "www."
```

then i have to use above variable in transforms?

Comment: Did you try anything about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C#, `Regex.Replace` is an equivalent of Python's `re.sub`. Mind that backreference styles differ: `\1` in Python replacement string is `$1` (and `\g<1>` is `${1}`) in C#.

The raw string literal in C# has a `@""` notation (equivalent of `r''` in Python).

You can use

```
//var url = "http://www.active.com"; // http://www.active.com
var url = "http://active.com"; // http://www.active.com
var domain_part = "www.";
var regex = new Regex(string.Format(@"(^htt[^/]*//)(?!{0})(.*)", Regex.Escape(domain_part)));
var res = regex.Replace(url, "$1" + domain_part + "$2");
Console.WriteLine(res);
```

See the [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/qTzSQe)

Explanations:

- `Regex.Escape(domain_part)` escapes the literal string for use inside a regex
- `(^htt[^/]*//)(?!{0})(.*)` contains a negative lookahead that will fail the match if there is already a domain_part inside the string
- `"$1" + domain_part + "$2"` inserts the dynamic domain part.